# Is there something like sessions in dart?

Tags: session, authentication, dart

This may seem like a silly question but I am just starting out with dart and will need to verify user sesions similar to what you might do with PHP with the $_SESSION array...

So I am writing a basic server backend and a frontend and need to authenticate some requests that come in via XMLHttpRequest. The backend sends back JSON based on whether the given frontend is authenticated or not. In some cases, the frontend can update the DOM but *only* for the user who authenticated.

Not sure if I am explaining this well...

Any advice would be appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: I searched for dart server-side web frameworks, which would implement sessions, and I found this: https://github.com/lvivski/start  There are probably others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A session is a high-level functionality that shouldn't be part of any language. You can include session functionality yourself by impelementing something like.

```dart
  Map<String, int> sessions = {'abcdef12345' : 42}; // exists in e.g. datastore and is managed by an authentication routine 

  String authenticationToken = 'abcdef12345'; // comes from the request
  if(sessions.containsKey(authenticationToken)) {
    print('User ${sessions[authenticationToken]} is at least authenticated but might not have the appropriate rights to perform this operation.');
  } else {
    print('Not authenticated.');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like sessions is built in, but you can check out the recent Google API library for Dart to use oAuth:

[Google API Dart Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dart-client/)

Comment: Interesting - will check this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The package [shelf_auth](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shelf_auth) provides a nice full-automatic solution for session handing with its `JwtSessionHandler` implementation for [shelf](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shelf)

```dart
var authMiddleware = authenticate([new RandomAuthenticator()],
      new JwtSessionHandler('super app', 'shhh secret', testLookup));
```

Comment: This is outdated and not maintained by now - is there anything comparable for Dart 2?

Answer (score 0):

Small example of using session with `shelf` package.

```
import 'dart:io' show Cookie;

import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart' as io;
import 'package:shelf_router/shelf_router.dart';
import 'package:shelf_session/cookies_middleware.dart';
import 'package:shelf_session/session_middleware.dart';
import 'package:shelf_static/shelf_static.dart';

void main(List<String> args) async {
  final router = Router();
  router.get('/', _handleHome);
  router.get('/login', _handleLogin);
  router.get('/login/', _handleLogin);
  router.post('/login', _handleLogin);
  router.post('/login/', _handleLogin);
  router.get('/logout', _handleLogout);
  router.get('/logout/', _handleLogout);
  final staticHandler =
      createStaticHandler('web', defaultDocument: 'index.html');
  final handler = Cascade().add(staticHandler).add(router).handler;
  final pipeline = const Pipeline()
      .addMiddleware(logRequests())
      .addMiddleware(cookiesMiddleware())
      .addMiddleware(sessionMiddleware())
      .addHandler(handler);
  const address = 'localhost';
  const port = 8080;
  final server = await io.serve(pipeline, address, port);
  print('Serving at http://${server.address.host}:${server.port}');
}

const _menu = '''
<a href="/">Home</a><br />
<a href="/login">Log in</a><br />
<a href="/logout">Log out</a><br />''';

Future<Response> _handleHome(Request request) async {
  final userManager = UserManager();
  final user = userManager.getUser(request);
  var body = '$_menu{{message}}<br />{{cookies}}';
  if (user == null) {
    body = body.replaceAll('{{message}}', 'You are not logged in');
  } else {
    body = body.replaceAll('{{message}}', 'You are logged in as ${user.name}');
  }

  final cookies = request.getCookies();
  body = body.replaceAll('{{cookies}}',
      cookies.entries.map((e) => '${e.key}: ${e.value}').join('<br />'));
  request.addCookie(Cookie('foo', 'Foo'));
  if (!cookies.containsKey('baz')) {
    request.addCookie(Cookie('baz', 'Baz'));
  } else {
    request.removeCookie(Cookie('baz', ''));
  }

  return _render(body);
}

Future<Response> _handleLogin(Request request) async {
  const html = '''
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Login</label><br />
<input name="login" type="text" /><br />
<label>Password</label><br />
<input name="password" type="password" /><br /><br />
<button>Log in</button>
</form>
''';

  if (request.method == 'GET') {
    return _render(_menu + html);
  }

  final body = await request.readAsString();
  final queryParameters = Uri(query: body).queryParameters;
  final login = queryParameters['login'] ?? ''
    ..trim();
  final password = queryParameters['password'] ?? ''
    ..trim();
  if (login.isEmpty || password.isEmpty) {
    return _render(_menu + html);
  }

  final user = User(login);
  final userManager = UserManager();
  userManager.setUser(request, user);
  return Response.found('/');
}

Future<Response> _handleLogout(Request request) async {
  Session.deleteSession(request);
  return Response.found('/');
}

Response _render(String body) {
  return Response.ok(body, headers: {
    'Content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  });
}

class User {
  final String name;

  User(this.name);
}

class UserManager {
  User? getUser(Request request) {
    final session = Session.getSession(request);
    if (session == null) {
      return null;
    }

    final user = session.data['user'];
    if (user is User) {
      return user;
    }

    return null;
  }

  User setUser(Request request, User user) {
    var session = Session.getSession(request);
    session ??= Session.createSession(request);
    session.data['user'] = user;
    return user;
  }
}
```